# Confused on how to use rust modules

Tags: rust, module

I have three files.  main.rs, foo.rs, bar.rs all in the src directory.  I want to use whats in foo.rs in bar.rs.  So i have mod foo; inside of bar.  But i get an error as shown below.  I do not want to put the foo.rs in a sub directory e.g. src/bar/foo.rs is there another way to structure the code? Because i want foo.rs to be used in many different places besides bar.rs. Optionally if you could tell me how you structure a big project with multiple files then that will suffice.

```
    file not found for module `foo`
     --> src/bar.rs:1:1
      |
    1 | mod foo;
      | ^^^^^^^^
      |
      = help: to create the module `foo`, create file "src/bar/foo.rs"

    error: aborting due to previous error
```

main.rs

```
mod bar;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

foo.rs

```
pub fn do_something() {
    
}
```

bar.rs

```
mod foo;
```

Comment: declare the `foo` module in your `main.rs`

Comment: actually this helped thanks!  I got something that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to declare modules once, and in this case you would declare both in `main` and then you would be able to import them from anywhere else in your codebase using `use crate::{mod_name}`. Example:

`src/main.rs`

```rust
// declare foo & bar modules
mod foo;
mod bar;

fn main() {
    foo::foo();
    foo::call_bar();
    bar::bar();
    bar::call_foo();
}
```

`src/foo.rs`

```rust
// import bar module
use crate::bar;

pub fn foo() {
    println!("foo");
}

pub fn call_bar() {
    bar::bar();
}
```

`src/bar.rs`

```
// import foo module
use crate::foo;

pub fn bar() {
    println!("bar");
}

pub fn call_foo() {
    foo::foo();
}
```